# DHCP pushed route to custom table on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking, dhcp, policy-routing, netplan

Is there a way I can direct routes that I receive from DHCP to a specific routing table depending on what interface it was received on?

E.g. eth0 and eth1 are both configured by DHCP. I would like the default route from eth0 to end up in my main table while the default route from eth1 should end up in another routing table.

I use Ubuntu with netplan to configure the network settings.